# How would I set up and manage someone else G-suite without a password?

Tags: google-workspace, privacy, account-management, passwords, google-workspace-for-business

Instead of running my own (low-quality) mail server, I advice my customers to use G-Suite instead and let me do the set up. For this service I charge them. However, every now and then an edit has to be done, such as adding a new domain or creating new users. Although it's a small task, they ask me to do this.

My only problem with this is privacy. As G-suite doesn't allow 'manager accounts' that don't have any functionality, besides managing the account, I always have to ask my clients for their password to log in and set-up the service.

I only have 6 clients, so I can't register for the reseller functionality. Despite that, I was hoping someone could advice me to how to arrange a support functionality for me.

Who has a suggestion how to handle these situations?

Answer (score 1):

Google does provide you the ability to have an admin account that doesn't have access to any of the Google applications other than the admin console and Groups for example. You will need to add a user with a Cloud Identity Free license and then assign that user admin rights.

You can read a bit more about it here and help improve that article as it is open for edits by anyone.

[NFTF: G Suite | Cloud Identity for Super Admins](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vixLaBDnZscskTPu1Q7ijxcVUsJR1OHtzbXpOX3tk5U/edit)